Custom Spring Cloud Stream binder being called for all bindings
In my spring boot application I am connecting to both GCP pub sub and RabbitMq using spring cloud stream bindings.
For pubsub I have created a custom binder (to override the need to have the subscription name in the format.).
But now the application uses the custom binder even for the Rabbit binding even though I am specifying the binder type in each binding.
Is there a way to make the binder to be invoked for specific binding?

I was able to make it work.
I had the custom binder configuration class annotated with @Configuration which was causing it to be automatically registered.
By Removing the @Configuration I was able to use the custom binder for specific binding.
